# How do I route data through personal domain after setting up ubuntu server

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, nginx, raspberry-pi, velo

So I am trying to get data from a raspberry pi every 500 miliseconds to an android app. I successfully got through [this][1] guide from digital ocean on How To Serve Flask Applications with uWSGI and Nginx on Ubuntu. The last step was entering your domain which I did. If I go to the domain, I see my usual website that I had set up through Wix. So I created a new page and set my Ubuntu server to that page, which still gave me a wix like page... But more importantly data does not seem to be passing through like it did when I used Flask to pass it locally. I have the errors on the  domain (wix website). But I'm not sure these are the issue. think I need to write some code to pass the data? I don't know where to go from here. Many, many thanks.

```
Unrecognized feature: 'vr'.
```

169Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab.
sentry-next.wixpress.com/api/68/store/?sentry_key=605a7baede844d278b89dc95ae0a9123&sentry_version=7:1

```
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 ()
```

chat-sdk.ts:17 [2024-03-22T00:04:33.890Z]  @firebase/app-compat:
Warning: Firebase is already defined in the global scope. Please make sure
Firebase library is only loaded once.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [sf] would be better places for questions like this.